# counting the vowels, without using raw input and the string 's' is defined.My result a infinite loop, whats wrong in it

Tags: python

```
k=0
if (s[-1] == "a" or s[-1] == "e" or s[-1] == "i" or s[-1] == "o" or s[-1] == "u"):
    k=1
else:
    K=0
t=len(s)-1
while t>=0:
if (s[t-1:t] == "a"  or  s[t-1:t] == "e"  or s[t-1:t] == "i" or s[t-1:t] == "o" or s[t-1:t] == "u"):

    t=t-1  

    k=k+1    

else:    

    t=t-1 
print "Number of vowels:", k
```

Comment: I tried running this and got `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. Please provide code that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please reformat your question, esp. the heading, deliver some information about your problem and provide a well formatted code.

Comment: To expand upon @albert 's comment, please read this [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Another approach: `sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in s.lower())`.  Another using regular expressions: `len(re.findall('[aeiou]', s, re.I))`.  (Of course, neither of these explain what's wrong with your code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use `for` loop to iterate every character from the string.

**Demo:**

```
In [28]: s = "qazxswedcvfrgbnhyujmkiopl"

In [29]: count = 0

In [30]: for i in s:
   ....:     if i.lower() in ["a", "i", "o", "u", "e"]:
   ....:         count += 1
   ....:         

In [31]: print count
5
```